# Shopify GraphQL to fetch Delivery Rate for Products

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to fetch products and their delivery rates from the `[deliveryProfiles]` object (or shipping profiles). Using the query below, I am able to pull all the products that are associated with a `[deliveryProfile]` but I can't figure out how to fetch the Delivery Rate for each product.

Our store only uses static shipping rates so I believe I need to use something like the `[rateProvider]` query below. But I don't know or even how to modified the query to include something like this.

```
rateProvider {... on DeliveryRateDefinition {id price {amount}
```

Current query I'm using:

```
query {
  deliveryProfiles (first: 5) {
    edges {
      node {
        profileItems (first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              product {
                  id
                  handle
              }
              variants (first: 10) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    title
                    sku
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It was simply a matter of understanding nesting. Here is how you fetch both products and delivery rates in Shopify using GraphQL API:

```
query {
  deliveryProfiles (first: 2) {
    edges {
      node {
        profileItems (first: 8) {
          edges {
            node {
              product {
                id
                handle
              }
              variants (first: 8) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    title
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        profileLocationGroups {
          locationGroupZones(first: 2) {
            edges {
              node {
                methodDefinitions(first: 2) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      rateProvider {
                        ... on DeliveryRateDefinition {
                          id
                          price {
                            amount
                          }
                        }
                        ... on DeliveryParticipant {
                          id
                          fixedFee {
                            amount
                            currencyCode
                          }
                          percentageOfRateFee
                          participantServices {
                            active
                            name
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @user9722, would this work when called from a script in the storefront? I was thinking of automatically displaying the estimated delivery time on the product page, but am unsure of how to get access to that data through the product handle. Thanks! :)